# How make just one Main method without “Program has more than one entry point defined” in Nunit testing (ASP.NET Core project, Visual Code)

Tags: api, asp.net-core, nunit

I created asp.net core project - `dotnet new web api` -
in Visual Studio Code (there were even no debugger support
with c# extension for x86 system).
Then I needed to implement Nunit tests.
I created with `dotnet new nunit` command in one of project
folder along with controller, repository, models folder.
Then I passed reference to outer project in test.csroj.
Indeed as it happened I needed to pass
to my main.csproj file
these automatically created dependencies to use
Nunit classes in my testfixture class files?!

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.11.0"/> 
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.11.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.9.0"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

So it seems that I could delete these references from
test.csproj where they were created during dotnet new nunit (indeed I left,
as probably it should not work without these duplicate too)...
Indeed here I got two autogenerated files with main method,
in addition to Main in basic Program.cs file - so I needed to comment
Main in last case to run nunit tests.
Here it seems to be main issue, I do not know how to absolve.
This  -

```
// <auto-generated> This file has been auto generated. </auto-generated>
    using System;
  [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestSDKAutoGeneratedCode]
    class AutoGeneratedProgram {static void Main(string[] args){}}
```

-appears in в Test.Program.cs(..testfolder\obj), 
and in MainProject.Program.cs (..MainProject\obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2).
Adding in Test.csproj - `<GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile>`,
did not solved problem
indeed false
solved with GenerateAssemblyInfo autogeneration.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Indeed this resourse 
https://andrewlock.net/fixing-the-error-program-has-more-than-one-entry-point-defined-for-console-apps-containing-xunit-tests/ tells that it should resolve CS0017 Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point.
Although I did not tried to use such writing as

```
<GenerateProgramFile Condition="'$(GenerateProgramFile)' == ''">true</GenerateProgramFile>
```

as I suggest it is the same as the previous proposal.
Moreover in some combinations there were dependency of my test autogenerated
Main() on outerproject obj Main() so with commented Main() in Program.cs it could not be launched 
in the whole. 
I also cannot add Exe в MyProject.csproj 
as it is web api, not console project.
So the only half-decision to temporary absolve autogenerated files with Main(),
and without commenting main() Program.cs
was to delete `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.9.0"/>` in MainProject.csproj
and left

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.11.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.11.0"/>
```

...
        with all three items in Test.csproj.
    So to dotnet test and dotnet run I need have obj folder deleted in Testsubfolder,
    or to have deleted just Tests.Program.cs file in BooksApi\Tests\obj\Debug \netcoreapp2.2
    that appear after running tests???
    What to do do absolve autogeneration of Main in the whole???

Comment: What is role PackageReference of "Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk"  why not use just NUnit3TestAdapter, indeed it seems that former one create console test output with results.

Comment: It seems to be easy question - how to unit test asp.net core in Visual Code. Why I need package reference in main project file too, how disable autogenerated files?

Comment: Where I could get answer, if not on stackoverflow??

Comment: Should nobody created nunit, xunit and other tests for asp.net core, without Visual Studio?? Let so, what about do it in Visual studio 2017 (csproj config files)?? Do you create it (just with dotnet new nunit) and run (dotnet test)  just from cmd line, and  - without using any Test Exporer for creation and running?? Maybe there is no issue about autogeneration files with recurring Main() method in Visual Studio Ide?

Comment: What was your solution @art? 3 Years later, i have the same issue when executing in our CI via dotnet test.